# List of indices of every value

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a single Numpy function that is equivalent to

```
[array == value for value in np.unique(array)]
```

or

```
[np.where(array == value) for value in np.unique(array)]
```

Or if not, a more efficient way to do this?  These iterate through the array `len(np.unique(array))` times, when you can do it in a single pass:

```
indices = defaultdict(list)
for index, value in enumerate(array):
    indices[value].append(index)
```

I'd like a solution that doesn't require an explicit for loop.

Comment: There are various ways to address this problem; which one is most appropriate depends a bit on the context; how you plan on using these results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is a mask with multiple unique number conditions, you can do it using `return_inverse` from [np.unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

Having a sample array

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(5, 10, size=100) # 100 [5-10) random numbers
```

And its unique numbers and inverse mapping

```
>>> unique, inverse = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
```

We can create a container with extra dimensions (`a.shape` + 1 dimension foe each unique number)

```
>>> indexes = np.zeros((a.shape[0], unique.size), dtype=np.bool)
```

And finally, fill the array with the inverse mapping:

```
>>> indexes[np.arange(a.size), inverse] = True
```

The `indexes` map contains `True` in the last dimension corresponding to the index of the *unique number* that it matches (the order in the `unique` array).

```
>>> indexes[:3, :]
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Each row corresponds to the index of your original array `a` and each column corresponds to a *unique number*.

Comment: @1" No problem! It is harder question if you want to check `N` conditions (different than *uniqueness*).. but for unique numbers this should do the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little ambiguous; but take a look at [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP); it seems like either npi.indices, npi.contains, or npi.in_ can be made to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks!  Anything in Numpy itself that's equivalent to this?